# how to add two 'time' datatypes in laravel?

Tags: laravel, time, php-carbon

I have a 'services' table having a column called 'duration'. Its datatype is time and data stored in this column like '00:30:00'
I also have another table for bookings having two columns 'start_time' and 'end_time'. Both columns datatype are also 'time'. I want to get summation of service->duration + booking->start_time and store it in the 'end_time' column. How can I add these two time data?

I tried something like this:

```
date('H:i:s', strtotime($booking_service->start_time) + strtotime($service->duration))
```

but it considers timezone offset and returns wrong result. How should I remove timezone offset? is there another better way such as using Laravel Carbon to sum these two times?